# How to determine view is backed in Kendo Mobile?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

Is there any way to know that view is open by back?

For example

```
<div data-role="view" id="view-test" data-show="show">
<!-- View content -->
</div>

<script>
var show = function(e){
    if(e.view.isBack())
    {
        console.log("Back")
        // do something
    } 
}
</script>
```

Is there any method or property like **e.view.isBack()** ?

Comment: Do you mean, is the view open because the user used the back button in the browser?

Comment: @whipdancer yes I mean it

Comment: There is no such method, what do you want to achieve? Is this because you want to avoid page reloading?

Comment: @Akis_Tfs Yes I want to avoid page reloading on back. It works for now with data-reload="true" . But I dont want to reload on back.

Comment: if i was you i would avoid the auto reload property and i would do a manual read of the datasource when it is needed

Comment: @Akis_Tfs I exactly want to do as your way. But I need to know that the view is opened by back or not. If there is no way to  know this I have to read datasource every on show view. Maybe there is another way, but I dont have idea.

Comment: alright, given that you havent provided a lot of code i made an answer please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to handle this, maybe you can use a global variable where you keep the last visited page or even you can add a back button handler and get the view from which the back button was pressed. Another solution would be to pass a parameter along with page navigation when going back, for example:

```
<a data-role="button" href="#foo?back=true">Link to FOO with back parameter set to true</a>
```

And on the visited page on show event you can get the parameter like this:

```
function fooShow(e) {
     e.view.params // {back: "true"}
}
```

Now depending on what the parameter value is you can detect if the back button was pressed or not before reaching the page.